# Where-used list of inactive objects

Tags: sap-bw

I am trying to find out where table RS3RDFLDNEW in BW is used. 
But it is giving me an error.
In the error documentation, it is explaining about inactive objects.

Can anyone tell me how to **display inactive objects for where used list**.
Basically, I want to know how table RS3RDFLDNEW is getting updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the where-used index is computed from the compiled version of programs, so I'd be surprised if it was possible to have inactive programs appear in the WUL (unless they have a previous active version, of course).

Comment: I was trying to find out how table RS3RDFLDNEW is getting updated. So using where used list I tried. Is there any way to find out this?

Comment: You have checked [note 28022](http://service.sap.com/support/notes/28022), I assume?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable table changes logging where you can track updates of any table.

1. Set `rec/client` parameter of your system either to ALL (log changes in all clients), or to client number. Instance restart needed.
2. Enable logging in table technical settings (use transaction SE13).
3. Check logs in transaction SCU3.